# Javascript constructor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I have some arrays and a simple constructor, but somehow i just can't get it work.

```
var suit = ["ruutu", "risti", "\u00E4rtu", "poti"],
    type = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "soldat", "emand", "kuningas", "\u00E4ss"],
    pnt = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11],
    card = {}, // 3 properties: suit, type, pnt)
    Cards = [];

Cards = makeDeck(card, suit, type, pnt, Cards);
card = new NewCard(Cards);

function makeDeck(card, suit, type, pnt, Cards) {
    "use strict";
    var i,
        j;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < 13; j = j + 1) {
            card = {
                suit : suit[i],
                type : type[j],
                pnt : pnt[j]
            };
            Cards.push(card);
        }
    }
    return Cards;
}

function NewCard(Cards) {
    "use strict";
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
    this.suit = Cards[i].suit;
    this.type = Cards[i].type;
    this.pnt = Cards[i].pnt;
}
```

I can see in Firebug, that while this.suit and this.type get their values, this.pnt remains undefined. Why? Does it have something to do with data type (numbers vs strings)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You code works for me.  If I put `alert(this.pnt);` immediately after `this.pnt = Cards[i].pnt;` the alert shows a number.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Same. Check out the console when you run this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XKrXx/

Comment: The problem is probably that i'm an overtired beginner in javascript. :) It works for me now. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again!